# Result of atan2 is not smooth

Tags: matlab, gradient, smoothing, atan2

I am using `atan2` (in MATLAB) to calculate angles, and then I take the gradient of the angle. I can see that the angle is not smooth at places like pi and pi/2, but that is not visible in the plot. Then, plotting the gradient of the angle shows big negative spikes. I can ignore these by setting the limits of the plot (`ylim`), but this is not a good generic solution.
Can I somehow avoid the smoothness issue, or smooth the angle after calculating it?

Here is some more background. I am using a numerical ODE solver (specifically SUNDIALS CVODE) to calculate planetary orbits in a 2-dimensional case, so the result is two time-dependent vectors, let's call them `x` and `y`. Then `atan2` gives me the angle, and the gradient of the angle gives me the angular velocity. I tried MATLAB `smoothdata`, but it didn't fix the problem at hand.

The code is just MATLAB `atan2` and `gradient`, except for the calculation of the orbits, but that should not be relevant to this question.

I need to get rid of the negative spikes in the angular velocity.

Comment: Can you show us some code and your plots?  It is hard to understand without a concrete example (see [mcve]). Also note that `atan2` returns values between `-pi` and `pi`. Are you maybe looking for [`unwrap`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html)?

Comment: Indeed, do spikes happen at locations where the angle flips from -pi to pi? You should plot your angle to verify this. If this is not the case, please post code and upload your plot so we can see it!

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your angular gradient magnitude should always be less than pi (or some other threshold between pi and two pi), then you can fix the gradient, `grad`, as follows:

```
if grad < pi
    grad = grad + 2 * pi;
elseif grad > pi
    grad = grad - 2 * pi;
end
```

If you don't have such a guarantee then you'll need to assume that the gradient changes smoothly, which requires a more complicated correction.

Comment: Many thanks to everyone who responded. I will add some data, plots, and code to this remark. Note that t is the time vector, and q1 & q2 are the Cartesian coordinates. Theta1 is the angle, and theta1Dot is the angular velocity.

Comment: The code:
 fh = figure();
        hold on;
        theta1 = atan2(q2,q1);
%         theta2 = smoothdata(theta1);
        theta1Dot = gradient(theta1,t(end)/length(t));
%         theta1DotD = diff(theta1)*length(t)/t(end);
%         theta2Dot = smoothdata(theta1Dot);
        yyaxis('left');
        ax = gca;
        ax.YColor='r';
        plot(t,theta1,'r-');
        ylim([-pi,pi]);
        ylabel('\theta','Color','r');
        yyaxis('right');

Comment: ax = gca;
        ax.YColor='b';
        plot(t,theta1Dot,'b-');
        ylim([18.5,19]); % special case for f01
        ylabel('\thetaDot','Color','b');
        grid('on');
        grid('minor');
        xlabel('t');
%         legend('\theta','Location','best');
%         legend('\theta','\dot{\theta}','Location','best');
        legend('\theta','\thetadot','Location','best');
        title(strrep(nameOrbit,'.txt','Data2'));

Comment: nameFig = strrep(nameOrbit,'.txt','Data2');
        nameFig = [DataDir, '\', nameFig];
        savefig(fh,nameFig);
        saveas(fh,nameFig,'jpeg');
        close(fh);

Comment: I really wanted to attach all data and all code, but the data was too big, the code required splitting, and the interface has lost the new lines. I am struggling with the basics of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I tried to use ctrl+G to add the image, but that just started a bot reading the post to me.

Comment: The code: 
    `fh = figure(); 
    hold on; 
    theta1 = atan2(q2,q1);
    % theta2 = smoothdata(theta1); 
    theta1Dot = gradient(theta1,t(end)/length(t)); 
    % theta1DotD = diff(theta1)*length(t)/t(end); 
    % theta2Dot = smoothdata(theta1Dot); 
    yyaxis('left'); 
    ax = gca; ax.YColor='r'; plot(t,theta1,'r-'); 
    ylim([-pi,pi]); 
    ylabel('\theta','Color','r'); 
    yyaxis('right');`

Comment: The code: 
    `fh = figure();   <br/>
    hold on;   
    theta1 = atan2(q2,q1); 
    % theta2 = smoothdata(theta1);   
    theta1Dot = gradient(theta1,t(end)/length(t));     
    % theta1DotD = diff(theta1)*length(t)/t(end);   
    % theta2Dot = smoothdata(theta1Dot);   
    yyaxis('left');   
    ax = gca; ax.YColor='r'; plot(t,theta1,'r-');   
    ylim([-pi,pi]);   
    ylabel('\theta','Color','r');   
    yyaxis('right');`

Comment: Sorry for taxing your patience. I have added backticks, 4 spaces before each line, and 2 spaces after each line, but it still doesn't appear in the final results.

Comment: Again, thanks to everyone who replied, and I apologize for my total failure in formatting my comments. I found a solution, and it is a better use of the smoothdata call, where I added a method and a window that is significantly larger than the default. So, in total, I have `theta1 = atan2(q2,q1);`,then `theta1Dot = gradient(theta1,t(end/length(t));`, and `theta2Dot = smoothdata(theta1Dot,'movmedian',10);`. After that, the plot is very good for its purpose, which is just for me to better understand the data.